# Safe login box for website - how to store the details for future visits

Tags: php, mysql, flash, cookies, security

I have a really, really poor understanding around security and safety when building websites - what I want to do is store the information the user enters to log in into a cookie so that I can do two things:

1. Check the cookie from flash (via a php file) to grab information about a logged in user (if at all). This will be used for highscore APIs, etc.
2. Automatically log in a user when they come back to my site.

The site itself doesn't really have any important information etc, so I mean it doesn't have the be the most secure thing on earth (or even close). But I'd like it to not be tampered with if possible.

From my understanding, storing user information in a cookie can be bad because the user can just alter the cookie and be logged in as someone else.

I was thinking; is it reasonably safe to do something like this?:

1. When the user logs in, store an MD5'd version of their email address (used to log in). This way at least it's extremely unlikely that they will be able to modify the information to reflect another user in the database.
2. Because someone could just MD5 an email address that they know someone else uses for the site and change their cookie to reflect that, should I maybe store their MD5'd password alongside it and then use these to attempt a login at every page? Only thing is that this seems like it would be slow/non-strategic because it's needing to basically re-login with the information in the cookie every page.

This approach probably seems really strange, but would it work fine? The main requirement I have is that if the user is logged into my site, playing my flash games anywhere on the internet will automatically pick up that they're logged in and work with their information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use PHP sessions.

Php stores the session id in a cookie on the browser, and everything else in the session is stored on the server. Your flash script should be able to the the session id from that cookie and maybe you can write a php file that will return the information that the flash file needs when the flash file passes in the session id?

Because session ids are more or less random, it is difficult for the user to change their session cookie and accidentially access the login of another user.

Comment: Sounds familiar, how do I work with the cookie that the session creates? I don't even know how to access it.

Comment: It is just a normal browser cookie. I think PHP uses the default cookie name of "PHPSESSID", but that is changable in your PHP scripts.

Comment: I'm having trouble finding information around this other than vague references to 'cookie based session' in php.net. If you have any resources/tutorials to offer I'll accept this answer.

Comment: Why are you not creating a page on your domain with start_session(); and then looking up the newly created cookie? Cookies are ONLY used in PHP sessions to store a session ID. The relevant data is all stored on the server and is accessed by a user providing their session_id from their cookie. iWantSimpleLife's answer is spot on.

Comment: Yes. You will need to create a php page on the server that accesses the session data. Those data is only available to the server and not the browser. The browser can only get the session id from the cookie (and nothing else).